# Get just subdirectory name from a multisite URL

Tags: multisite, regex

I want to get just the subdirectory name from the network site, and I've gone through the codex and cannot find a function that already does this.

I have come up with a few options to get to the point I need, but I wanted to know if there was either:

1. a function I havent seen yet
2. which of these options works the best and efficiently

Option 1:

```
$url = get_bloginfo( 'url' );                     // output http://example.com/site1
$str = preg_replace( '#^https?://#', '', $url );  // output example.com/site1
$dom = parse_url( $url );
$dom = str_replace( 'www.', '', $dom['host'] );   // output example.com

$out = str_replace( $dom . '/', '', $str );       // just the subdirectory
```

Option 2:

```
$url = get_blog_details()->path;                 // output /site1/
$dom = str_replace( '/', '', $url );             // output site1
```

Obviously option 2 is less lines, but I'm not sure if it is the most efficient or cleanest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing more efficient code-wise than your Option 2 would be this one-liner:

```
<?php
$dom = str_replace( '/', '', get_blog_details()->path );
```